Magento2 incorrect position of price calender in admin panel
I recently upgraded Magento from version 2.4.6 to 2.4.7-p3. After the upgrade, I noticed that the 'Special Price From' and 'Special Price To' calender have been moved to the bottom of the product page.
I've already tried removing all custom modules, but the issue persists on my existing website. To rule out any conflicts, I also installed a fresh Magento 2.4.7-p3 instance, and the 'Special Price From' and 'Special Price To' calender are displayed correctly in the default installation.


did you try rebuilding the static resources?

Yes, multiple times
